# Error validating XML

Tags: xml, validation, netbeans

I have created an XML schema and also a corresponding XML file, and I'm trying to validate them. Although Notepad++ passes the validation, when trying to validate it through Netbeans I get a "cannot find element schedule" error. Schedule is the root element. After some tries I found that the error is in the namespace declarations. I am not that experienced with XML, so details like namespaces still confuse me. Any help?

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="schedule"
    xmlns="schedule"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="Schedule">
```

And the xml file:

```
<Schedule xmlns="schedule"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schedule.xsd">
</Schedule>
```

Of course there are lines in between those elements, like element types and subelements, but I didn't include them to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've included xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation in the instance but this isn't a no-namespace schema. You need to use xsi:schemaLocation (whose value is a pair containing the namespace URI and the location of the corresponding schema document).